# Deleting whitespaces before a certain characters with regex

Tags: java, regex

Say, I have a string like the first line and I need to convert it to the second line.

```
"English       ,Spanish         ,Eastern Japanese          "
"English,Spanish,Eastern Japanese"
```

As you see, there are several whitespaces before commas, but each element may have spaces between its variables, too (like "Eastern Japanese"). So, all I need is to delete multiple whitespaces coming before commas. I can trim the last occuring whitespaces before using `replaceAll()` method, that is no problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can remove excessive spaces with `replaceAll`:

```
  String s = "English      ,Spanish".replaceAll("\\s+,",",");
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/nYzr3I)

Or with `trim()`:

```
System.out.println("English      ,Spanish    ".replaceAll("\\s+,",",").trim());
```

Another [demo](http://ideone.com/AxHqDI)

And another hint: if there are spaces to trim after `,`, add `\\s*` after `,` in the pattern:

```
.replaceAll("\\s+,\\s*",",")
```

Comment: Like question, like answer :)